# How to execute the output of another command

Tags: shell, sh

I have a CSV file where I would like to modify the following string:

```
${GDATEF(-4D,ddMMyyyy)}
```

To do so I am using the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "replacing >>D,ddMMyyyy)<<"
sed -i "s/D,ddMMyyyy)\}/ days\\\\\"\ \+\\\\\"%d\/%m\/%Y\\\\\"/g" $1


echo "replacing >>\${GDATEF(<< AND executing date + N days"
sed -i "s/\${GDATEF(/date -d \\\\\"`date` + /g" $1

echo "the final touch ;)"
sed -i "s/date -d /date -d/g" $1
```

This results in:

```
date -d\"Fri Oct 15 10:38:20 UTC 2021 + -4 days\" +\"%d/%m/%Y\"
```

Now I can take that result, remove some unnecessary characters and execute it manually:

```
sh-4.2# date -d "Fri Oct 15 09:20:53 UTC 2021 + -4 days" +"%d/%m/%Y"
11/10/2021
```

However, I would like to be able to perform that last step automatically, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the final result and use `sed` to remove `\`:

```sh
echo "date -d\"Fri Oct 15 10:38:20 UTC 2021 + -4 days\" +\"%d/%m/%Y\"" | sed 's+\\++'
```

This will output:

```sh
date -d"Fri Oct 15 10:38:20 UTC 2021 + -4 days" +"%d/%m/%Y"
```

If you execute that you will get:

```sh
11/10/2021
```

**TL;DR**

Here is the all in one solution:

```sh
eval $(echo "date -d\"Fri Oct 15 10:38:20 UTC 2021 + -4 days\" +\"%d/%m/%Y\"" | sed 's+\\++')
```